# infinite loop in wp_query using simple query

Tags: wp-query

This code goes into an infinite loop! What am i doing wrong? There is only one post called “hello there”. The only way to stop it is use `break;` in while.

Any help appreciated

```
 $gotop="hello there";

$args = array(

    's' => $gotop,
    'post_type' => 'post'

);

$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);

if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) :  ?>

        <?php

        while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) {
      $wp_query->the_post();
}

else:
  echo "nothing found.";
endif;
?>
```

Comment: Don't use `$wp_query` as the variable name for your custom query. It's [reserved](https://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables) for the main query. Can  I ask why you're using a custom query for search? Is this your search.php template?

Comment: i need custom query. i have to search for 'hello there' in my content-single.php

Comment: you were right the $wp_query was the issue. i renamed it and worked! please write the answer to accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not certain why it would cause an infinite loop, but make sure not to use `$wp_query` as the variable name for your custom query. It's a [reserved global variable](https://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables) for the main query. Use a different name for the variable. I'd also suggest using `wp_reset_postdata()` after the loop:

```
$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
        $my_query->the_post();
    }
else:
  echo "nothing found.";
endif;

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 1):

add wp_reset_query(); after while loop.

```
$gotop="hello there";

$args = array(

    's' => $gotop,
    'post_type' => 'post'

);

$my_query = new WP_Query($args);

if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) :  

        while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
             $my_query->the_post();
        }
        wp_reset_query();

else:
  echo "nothing found.";
endif;
```

let me know if this works for you!

Comment: works but the problem was the $wp_query name... i changed it to another random name and it worked!

Answer (score -1):

According to WP codex, have_posts() will return True on success, false on failure.
Calling this function within the loop will cause an infinite loop. So you need to use **endwhile**;

```
    $gotop="hello there";

$args = array(

    's' => $gotop,
    'post_type' => 'post'

);

$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);

if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) :  ?>

        <?php

        while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) {
      $wp_query->the_post();
      endwhile;
}

else:
  echo "nothing found.";
endif;
?>
```

Comment: This will cause a fatal error. They already have an `endwhile`, because they opened the `while` statement with a `{`, so it needs to be closed with a `}`, which they have.